# Select non-aggregate column in a group by, based on a related aggregate column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to get a list of conversations out of a database, and I'd like the most recent message to be displayed along with them. I'm having trouble finding a query that lets me do it (and which isn't N+1).

I have these tables:

```
chats(id, user_id, post_id, created_at)
messages(id, user_id, chat_id, body, created_at)
```

I had a query like this in mind:

```
select chats.id, chats.user_id, m.latest from chats
inner join (
    select chat_id, max(created_at) as latest from messages
    group by chat_id
) as m on m.chat_id = chats.id;
```

But I want to add the message body from the row corresponding to the `max(created_at)` result. Is it possible to get a related column like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With standard SQL this can be done using window functions (see sagi's answer).

With Postgres, the proprietary `distinct on()` is often faster than the equivalent solution using a window function:

```
select chats.id, chats.user_id, m.body, m.latest 
from chats
  join (
    select distinct on (chat_id) chat_id, body, created_at as latest 
    from messages
    order by chat_id, created_at desc;
  ) as m on m.chat_id = chats.id;
```

---

The solution using a window function is more flexible though. You could also get the latest two (or three or ...) messages with that, whereas `distinct on()` will only get you one.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
select chats.id, chats.user_id, m.body from chats
inner join (
    select chat_id,body ,
           row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY chat_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) as rnk
    from messages
) m on m.chat_id = chats.id and m.rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about window functions